# import android.preview.support.wearable.notifications.WearableNotifications;

Tags: android, notifications

I have a problem with "Stacking Notifications For Android". 
So, It was show error when i try to import "**import android.preview.support.wearable.notifications.WearableNotifications;**"

How to import this class?

Thx for your support.

--

[D]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some wear class names and packages [have changed from the preview to the full sdk](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/porting-your-wear-developer-preview.html):

> Since the APIs and package names have changed, the import statements at the top of MainActivity.java need to be adjusted like this:

```
-import android.preview.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
-import android.preview.support.wearable.notifications.WearableNotifications;
+import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
+import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
```